# php curl_exec returns empty

Tags: php, curl

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); // $proxy is ip of proxy server
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // this results 0 every time
 echo '<br> curl'.$ch; //this line outputs resource id#5
 $exec = stripslashes(curl_exec($ch)); 
 echo '<br> exec'.curl_exec($ch); //this results blank
```

i am confused why $exec does not return anything ,i am new to curl please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[curl_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) will return `false` when the request failed. Adjust your function to this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); // $proxy is ip of proxy server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // this results 0 every time
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) 
    $response = curl_error($ch);

echo stripslashes($response);

curl_close($ch);
```

This way u'll see the curl error

Comment: s/stripslaches/stripslashes/

Comment: thanks for , got the error 'could,nt connect to host' after searching found the error was due to proxy server

Comment: You can also add `curl_errno($ch)` to get the error number (or `0` if no error occurred).

Comment: With all due respect: the asking user stated, that the return result was empty, not false, which is a big difference. Empty doesn't mean an error occured. (I have the same problem.)

Comment: @Jasie [`echo false;`](https://ideone.com/xM8BlP) will actually show an empty screen, which was the case in OP's situation

Comment: Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to access a HTTP response code before you actually make the HTTP call. Reverse the execution as follows:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // this results 0 every time
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
```

Maybe the response is longer than 10.

I had the same issue, I solved like this.

Answer (score 1):

The result return 0 mean that you can not connect to the server so please recheck your  proxy and increase the timeout :)

Comment: "you can not connect to the server so please recheck your proxy" thanx it worked