# Curl - Couldn't connect to server from webserver

Tags: php, curl

```
         $url="http://www.bkashcluster.com:9080/dreamwave/merchant/trxcheck/sendmsg?user=username&pass=my_password&msisdn=01762623195&trxid={$transaction_id}";

         $headers = array(
                        "Content-type: application/xml");

         $ch = curl_init();

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);  
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");  
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");  
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");  
          $st=curl_exec($ch);
          $transaction_array=json_decode($st);

          return $transaction_array;
```

When i execute this code from my localhost i get the result successfully. But when i upload it to webserver (rajit.net) i couldn't get any result.

Comment: check for [curl_error()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121324/php-curl-exec-returns-empty/27121442#27121442)

Comment: is curl installed in your webserver?

Comment: Yea Curl is installed in my webserver. i can access other site with curl from my server.But problem is for that server. @fortune

Comment: error number : 7 
error: Coudln't connect the host @DarkBee

Comment: Your host prolly blocks connections to non-80 ports

Comment: What should i do now? what is the solution? Is there any solution @DarkBee

Comment: U could try to contact your host to ask why you are not able to fetch a curl on port 9080 or try to find out if u can fetch the requested XML through another URL/API