# Php cUrl doesn't works but boomerang/postman works

Tags: php, curl

I work with boomerang, but it's more or less the same as postman (i think).
With Boomerang i can do the call normally, but when i tried to do the same with php i can't.

here the two headers:

BOOMERANG / POSTMAN

```
GET https://example.es/api/bla/bloum/174 HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Basic ajklfsdkjfalksjdflñaskjdflakjdf=
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Result-MaxResults: 1
X-Result-CurrentPage: 1
X-Result-MaxPages: 1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 08:24:22 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

MY CODE

```
GET /api/bla/bloum/174 HTTP/1.1

Host: example.es
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic ajklfsdkjfalksjdflñaskjdflakjdf=
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Result-MaxResults: 1
X-Result-CurrentPage: 1
X-Result-MaxPages: 1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 08:24:22 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I can't put the url in the same way that Boomerang show, and i don't know if it's the problem.

POSTMAN CODE

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.es/api/bla/bloum/174",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Basic ajklfsdkjfalksjdflñaskjdflakjdf=",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "date: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 08:24:22 GMT",
        "postman-token: FJKFK",
        "server: Apache-Coyote/1.1",
        "transfer-encoding: chunked",
        "x-result-currentpage: 1",
        "x-result-maxpages: 1",
        "x-result-maxresults: 1"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
```

UPDATE

$error = curl_error($ch); // "Empty reply from server"

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // 0

UPDATE 2.0

I use POSTMAN to genereate the code and now the error is:
"Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"

without:
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30 //"Empty reply from server"

Comment: You to need to [test](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27121442/446594) wether the curl excuted succesful or not

Comment: $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // 0

Comment: Postman can export your HTTP request to a PHP cURL snippet. Did you try that yet?

Comment: Ohhh, great. but now my error is "Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" (in postman works and i copy the code)

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.es/api/asd/zxc/123',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'authorization: Basic ghfgfiytfgfigfkgfkgjkbvjkhgkjhgkjhg',
        'cache-control: no-cache',
        'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'server: Apache-Coyote/1.1',
        'x-result-currentpage: 3',
        'x-result-maxpages: 1',
        'x-result-maxresults: 1'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  $this->logger->error($err);
}
```

But i don't know why, sorry.

I export it with POSTMAN, and the second time it works...