# CURL request works via command line but not in PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

The below command is working perfect in command line.

```
curl -X POST "http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/upload?id=123456" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@a.pdf;type=application/pdf"
```

When i hit above command using command line it gives a token in return response.If i also call through `POSTMAN` it works fine.
But when i request through
PHP CURL it doesn't give neither any error nor token in response.I copied PHP-CURL code from `POSTMAN`

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/upload?id=123456",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFILE('/C:/Users/User/Downloads/c.pdf')),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Use correct case: `CURLFile`

Comment: Did you enable the curl extension in your php.ini?

Comment: @DarkBee yes,i enabled curl extension.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27121442/446594)

Comment: @DarkBee thanks.I am getting error `couldn't open file` but file exist on location.

Comment: Not sure what the first slash is doing in your filepath, anyway better to use backslashes in windowns env anyway, e.g. `new CURLFILE('C:\Users\User\Downloads\c.pdf')`

Answer (score -2):

Try to add `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to your request like
`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data')`